# Angular 5 and services in lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-template

I would like to ask a question regarding angular 5 application structure and maybe it is even related to the architecture of it. I have an application that is using lazy loading. I got to a point in which I need to make the same api call from 2 different lazy loaded modules. I would like to know how to approach this problem if anybody can help me with it

Comment: Do you have a shared module? You can have a common shared module containing the service making that call and importing it in the two others

Comment: yes, i do have a shared module but i was reluctant do add this api call in there. I see your point maybe this is the approach. Thank you

Comment: You don't really need a shared module. You can register the service in the `providers` array of the app module and it will be available to any lazy loaded module. This is even easier in Angular 6 using the new `providedIn` property (though I know you mentioned Angular v5).

Comment: @Deborahk so i should not register the providers in the module of each lazy loaded module, instead i should register them straight into the app module which will store all the providers for the entire app ? please correct me if i misunderstood .

Comment: Yes. If you want to "share" the services among multiple modules, then register the service with the app module and *not* with the lazy loaded modules.

Answer (score 2):

When you provide a service in Angular it is available everywhere. Only services provided in a lazy loaded module are not available throughout the app, because they will be instanciated when your module loads, not before.

When you need a service in the whole app, then you must provide it in a eagerly loaded module. Common pattern would be a core module, which holds all services and is loaded by the app.module.

Services provided in eagerly loaded modules can be injected everywhere even in lazy loaded modules.